# Equality of copy.copy and copy.deepcopy in python copy module

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am creating a list of numpy arrays then copying it to another array to keep an original copy. Copying was done using `deepcopy()` function. When I am comparing the two arrays now, it is showing false in equivalence. But its all good when I am using `copy()` function .I understand the difference between copy and deepcopy function, but shall the equivalence be not same?

That is:

```
 grid1=np.empty([3,3],dtype=object)
 for i in xrange(3):
    for j in xrange(3):
        grid1[i][j] = [i,np.random.uniform(-3.5,3.5,(3,3))]


 grid_init=[]
 grid_init=copy.deepcopy(grid1)
 grid1==grid_init      #returns False

 grid_init=[]
 grid_init=copy.copy(grid1)
 grid1==grid_init      #returns True

 grid_init=[]
 grid_init=copy.deepcopy(grid1)
 np.array_equal(grid1,grid_init)      #returns False
```

Shall all be not true?

Comment: Why are you using `dtype=object`?  Why not a `(3,3,3,3)` array, or a list of lists of these arrays?  It is hard to predict which actions (comparisons, copies) cross that `object` boundary.

Comment: Because each element is in itself will be rather complicated hybrid of numpy array and other elements. Hence i read that easiest way to make such arbitrary arrays would be with dtype=object. (each element is supposed to store id of a molecule and coordinates of all its atoms in my problem)

Comment: The `grid_init=[]` lines do nothing for you.

Comment: OK. Just wanted to ensure that any previous data was not present in the list or array

Comment: Ok, after actually doing a copy-n-paste, I see that the elements of `grid1` are not arrays, but lists, an integer and a 3x3 array.  To do meaningful copies and comparisons you have to keep track of when it is working with arrays and when it is working with lists.  The 2 objects don't behave the same.

Comment: `x=[]` does not empty out the previous value of `x`.  It replaces it with a new, empty list.  The next `x=...` tosses aside that empty list, and assigns a new value.

Comment: I've added an alternative array dtype - one that makes a structured array.  It avoids this nested lists and arrays problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must be running a different version of numpy/python, but I get slightly different errors and/or results.  Still the same issue applies - mixing arrays and lists can produce complicated results.

Make the 2 copies

```
In [217]: x=copy.copy(grid1)
In [218]: y=copy.deepcopy(grid1)
```

Equality with the shallow copy, gives a element by element comparison, a 3x3 boolean:

```
In [219]: x==grid1
Out[219]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

The elements are 2 item lists:

```
In [220]: grid1[0,0]
Out[220]: 
[0, array([[ 2.08833787, -0.24595155, -3.15694342],
        [-3.05157909,  1.83814619, -0.78387624],
        [ 1.70892355, -0.87361521, -0.83255383]])]
```

And in the shallow copy, the list ids are the same.  The 2 arrays have different data buffers (`x` is not a view), but they both point to the same list objects (located else where in memeory).

```
In [221]: id(grid1[0,0])
Out[221]: 2958477004
In [222]: id(x[0,0])
Out[222]: 2958477004
```

With the same `id` the lists are equal (they also satisfy the `is` test).

```
In [234]: grid1[0,0]==x[0,0]
Out[234]: True
```

But `==` with the deepcopy produces a simple `False`.  No element by element comparison here.  I'm not sure why.  Maybe this is an area in which `numpy` is undergoing development.

```
In [223]: y==grid1
Out[223]: False
```

Note that the deepcopy element ids are different:

```
In [229]: id(y[0,0])
Out[229]: 2957009900
```

When I try to apply `==` to an element of these arrays I get an error:

```
In [235]: grid1[0,0]==y[0,0]
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This is the error that comes up repeatedly in SO questions, usually because people try to use an boolean array (from a comparison) in a scalar Python context.

I can compare the arrays with in the lists:

```
In [236]: grid1[0,0][1]==y[0,0][1]
Out[236]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

I can reproduce the ValueError with a simpler comparison - 2 lists, which contain an array.  On the surface they look the same, but because the arrays have different ids, it fails.

```
In [239]: [0,np.arange(3)]==[0,np.arange(3)]
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This pair of comparisons shows what is going on:

```
In [242]: [0,np.arange(3)][0]==[0,np.arange(3)][0]
Out[242]: True
In [243]: [0,np.arange(3)][1]==[0,np.arange(3)][1]
Out[243]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Python compares the respective elements of the lists, and then tries to perform a logical operation to combine them, `all()`.  But it can't perform `all` on `[True, array([True,True,True])]`.

So in my version, `y==grid1` returns `False` because the element by element comparisons return `ValueErrors`.  It's either that or raise an error or warning.  They clearly aren't equal.

In sum, with this array of lists of number and array, equality tests end up mixing array operations and list operations.  The outcomes are logical, but complicated.  You have to be keenly aware of how arrays are compared, and how lists are compared.  They are not interchangeable.

### A structured array

You could put this data in a structured array, with a `dtype` like

```
 dt = np.dtype([('f0',int),('f1',float,(3,3))])

In [263]: dt = np.dtype([('f0',int),('f1',float,(3,3))])
In [264]: grid2=np.empty([3,3],dtype=dt)
In [265]: for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
                grid2[i][j] = (i,np.random.uniform(-3.5,3.5,(3,3)))
   .....:         
In [266]: grid2
Out[266]: 
array([[ (0, 
    [[2.719807845330254, -0.6379512247418969, -0.02567206509563602],
     [0.9585030371031278, -1.0042751112999135, -2.7805349057485946], 
     [-2.244526250770717, 0.5740647379258945, 0.29076071288760574]]),
....]])]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8', (3, 3))])
```

The first field, integers can be fetched with (giving a 3x3 array)

```
In [267]: grid2['f0']
Out[267]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

The second field contains 3x3 arrays, which when accessed by field name are a 4d array:

```
In [269]: grid2['f1'].shape
Out[269]: (3, 3, 3, 3)
```

A single element is a record (or tuple),

```
In [270]: grid2[2,1]
Out[270]: (2, [[1.6236266210555836, -2.7383730706629636, -0.46604477485902374], [-2.781740733659544, 0.7822732671353201, 3.0054266762730473], [3.3135671425199824, -2.7466097112667103, -0.15205961855874406]])
```

Now both kinds of copy produce the same thing:

```
In [271]: x=copy.copy(grid2)
In [272]: y=copy.deepcopy(grid2)
In [273]: x==grid2
Out[273]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
In [274]: y==grid2
Out[274]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Since `grid2` is pure `ndarray` (no intermediate lists) I suspect `copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy` end up using `grid2.copy()`.   In `numpy` we normally use the array copy method, and don't bother with the `copy` module.

p.s. it appears that with `dtype=object`, `grid1.copy()` is the same as `copy.copy(grid1)` - a new array, but the same object pointers (i.e. same data).

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, i initially was trying that only but gave up in favor of objects as was not able to get it right!! But i am just curious as to why my approach was wrong? what python was exactly doing?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm getting when running the first example:

```
WARNING:py.warnings:/usr/local/bin/ipython:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise the error in the future.
```

To see why the elementwise comparison fails, simply try to compare a single element:

```
grid_init=copy.deepcopy(grid1)
grid_init[0][0] == grid1[0][0]
>>> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This fails because the second element in the list is in itself a numpy array, and comparison of two numpy arrays does not return a bool (but an array).

---

Now, why does the example case behave differently?

Seems to be some interpreter optimization which avoid the actual comparison logic if the two objects are the same one. The two are the same object, because the copying was shallow.

```
grid_init=copy.copy(grid1)
grid_init[0][0] is grid1[0][0]
> True
grid_init[0][0] == grid1[0][0]
> True
```

---

The root cause is that you're using **a numpy array of dtype=object, with lists in it**. This is not a good idea, and can lead to **all sorts of weirdnesses**.

Instead, you should simply create 2 aligned arrays, one for the first element in your lists, and one for the second.

Comment: Pretty sure that numpy lets you mix data types if you're explicit about it